# MySQL get distinct values from arbitrarily long arrays of strings across rows

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, mysql-5.7

I have a table with a JSON column, let's call it `json_data` and the column contents look like...

```sql
[{ "data": { ... }, "name": "name_1" }, { "data": { ... }, "name": "name_2" }]
[{ "data": { ... }, "name": "name_2" }]
[{ "data": { ... }, "name": "name_3" }, { "data": { ... }, "name": "name_5" }]
[{ "data": { ... }, "name": "name_4" }]
```

...and I am looking to get back

```sql
["name_1", "name_2", "name_3", "name_4", "name_5"]
```

or something of that sort. I can use `JSON_EXTRACT` to quite easily get each row's set of name fields...

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, "$**.name") FROM my_table;
```

...so now I have rows each containing a single array of comma separated strings, and can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to merge them...

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(names SEPARATOR ','), '[', ''), ']', '')
FROM (
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, '$**.name') as names 
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE json_data <> '' -- exclude empty entries
    LIMIT 10) x -- test on sample size as the table is quite large
ORDER BY NULL; -- get names from all rows
```

...at this point I have all the data that I want in a single row as comma separated strings...

```sql
"name_1","name_2","name_2","name_3","name_4","name_5"
```

except that it has duplicates (MANY of them).

It seems like it should be easy to take this and run distinct on it, but so far I cannot figure out how to split the string into all the elements and perform distinct. `SUBSTRING_INDEX` seems to be what I need, but that only gets individual elements... any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern versions of MySQL (>= 8.0.4) the query would be relatively simple:

```sql
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT JSON_QUOTE(`der`.`names`)
  ) `names`
FROM
  `my_table`,
  JSON_TABLE(`my_table`.`json_data`,
    '$[*]' COLUMNS(
      `names` VARCHAR(10) PATH '$.name'
    )
  ) `der`
ORDER BY
  `names`;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e97ZRh53RDsrpw9uQGvdTi/1).

However, in older versions, it's not that simple, one option may be to use a temporary table and a prepared statement:

```sql
SET @`ddl` := CONCAT('INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ',
  (SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            `json_data` -> '$**.name',
          '[', '('),
        ']', ')'),
      ',', '),(')
    )
  FROM
    `my_table`
  )
);
```

See [Rextester](http://rextester.com/GESIWQ6142).

In any case, remember [5.1.7 Server System Variables::group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).